# Zabbix Custom Widget - Time selector

Tags: php, widget, zabbix

I am currently creating a custom Zabbix widget module, to visualize some data.

But got a bit stuck in how i can get the time selector period from the dashboard settings. (Top of the dashboard)

Do anyone have an idea where i can look this up ? Or could provide an example on how to ?
And also, i haven't been able to find a proper documentation page with the Widget / module development API's, in zabbix. Does there exist anything else than the Create a widget from the zabbix webpage (tutorial) ?

I expect to be able to get the to and from time defined in the timeselector in the top of the dashboard page.